# JSON syntax for a combined query using a structured query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm programatically building a combined query to use with the `/v1/search` REST endpoint and I'm just a bit confused about the correct syntax for a combined query that contains a structured query. The combined query starts with a `search` element and a `query` element contains the structured query. The structured query example I coudl find start with a `query` element and put the queries into a `queries` array. So that means my combined query would look like:

```
{ "search": {
  "query": {
    "query": { 
      "queries": [
        {"term-query":{"text":["foo"]}}
      ]
    }
  }
}}
```

So what I guess I'm really asking is it `/search/query/query/queries[]` or is it `/search/query/queries[]`?

Comment: Any of the following should work: /search/query/queries/ARRAY_OF_QUERIES, /search/query/SINGLE_QUERY, or /query/SINGLE_QUERY

Answer (score 0):

The extra `query.queries` looks a bit odd, but it is conform syntax, and works. You can also drop the `term-query` (or any other query) directly under `search.query`. This works too:

```
{
  "search": {
    "query": {
      "and-query": {
        "queries": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTH!